# How to select string before this or that using regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to select the string from before some characters

Example

Input

```
test1_day1_20204503642_sye_somestring-signed.bin
test2_day2_20205032456_ade_signed.bin
test2_day3_20204503425_arj.bin
```

Output

```
test1_day1_20204503642_sye_somestring
test2_day2_20205032456_ade
test2_day3_20204503425_arj
```

I want to remove -signed.bin,_signed.bin and .bin from the string. How can I do this by using regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes I tried this (.*?)\.bin. here i am not able to add group to check -signed

Comment: Match `(?:[_-]signed)?\.bin$` and replace with `""`. Check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/0Wchep/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern `([-_]signed){0,1}.bin$` and replace those characters with space

Let us take the below code in Perl

```
$str = 'test1_day1_20204503642_sye_somestring-signed.bin'
$extracted_str =~ s/([-_]signed){0,1}\.bin$//gi
print $extracted_str
```

Comment: Thank you shreyaskar. Both your's and @anubhava 's answer are working.

Comment: `.` should be escaped in regex and `{0,1}` can be written as `?`

Comment: @anubhava yes. that's a good practice. thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Not just good practice, an unescaped dot can give wrong result as it will match `-bin` and `Xbin` also at the end.